# "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" when it should be defined

Tags: typescript

```
interface IField {
  readonly name : string;
  readonly value : string;
  readonly inline ?: boolean;
}

class Field implements IField {
  readonly name : string;
  readonly value : string;
  readonly inline ?: boolean;

  constructor(data : IField) {
    this.name = data.name;
    this.value = data.value;
    this.inline = data.inline;
  }
}
```

When trying to initialize a new variable from the `Field` class inside another class like so,

```
class Embed implements IEmbed {
  ...

  constructor(data : IEmbed) {
    ...

    this.fields = data.fields.map((field) => new Field(field));

    ...
  }
}
```

My program crashes with the error,

```
        this.name = data.name;
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

If I log the value of `data` inside the `constructor(...)` method for `Field`, it prints out the object without any issue (changed values for privacy),

```
{
  value: '...message...',
  name: '...name...',
  inline: false
}
```

But it still crashes. The value given to the `Embed` constructor is a parsed JSON object from a websocket, and thus the same is true for the `Field` constructor.

Comment: What's IEmbed ?

Comment: The interface for Embed, although I just pass the JSON data from the websocket to the constructor's data parameter for it.

Comment: We know it's an interface but it's definition is missing. As for the error, if a field is null, the copy constructor will fall like yours does.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521447/typescript-pass-to-constructor-entire-object).

```
class Field implements IField {
  readonly name : string;
  readonly value : string;
  readonly inline ?: boolean;

  constructor(data : Partial<Field> = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }
}
```

I replaced the `data : any` portion with `data : Partial<Field> = {}`, providing a default for the field. Thanks to Wiktor for steering me in the right direction.